# How to fix 'parse error on input ‘=’' when compile the following quicksort example?

Tags: linux, haskell, ghci

put the code below into a .hs file, tried to import it by ":t xx.hs", but got an error.. I suspect it's syntax problem after seeing other questions.Hopefully someone could help me out.

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
  let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a  xs, a <= x]
       biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a  xs, a > x]
  in smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

get error:

Not in scope: ‘a’
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indentation of the two declarations in the `let` clause should match, like:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
  let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
      biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  -- no extra spacing
  in smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

In your original question, you also forgot to use the `<-` operator in the generator expression part of your list comprehension: you should thus write `a <- xs`, instead of `a xs`.

You can however, as [@RobinZigmond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934254/how-to-fix-parse-error-on-input-when-compile-the-following-quicksort-examp/55934326?noredirect=1#comment98521378_55934326) says, add spaces before and after the `=`, as long as you have the same number of spaces before the first non-space character, this is fine, like:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
  let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]
      biggerSorted  = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  -- extra space before =
  in smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

Note that you can use [**`partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition) to split a list in two lists where the first sublist has elements that satisfy the predicate, and the latter has the elements that do *not* satisfy the predicate, like:

```
import Data.List(partition)

quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
  let (smal, big) = partition (x >) xs
  in quicksort smal ++ x : quicksort big
```

The `partition` function is normally implemented in such way that it iterates only once over the given list, and only performs the test once. So this is typically (a bit) more efficient than using two list comprehensions that each individually filter the given list.

Comment: it might be worth adding that there's no harm in adding an extra space (or as many spaces as are desired) between the `biggerSorted` and the `=`, if the desire is for the `=` signs to be in the same column. (I have seen this done in code examples online.) The only important thing, as you say, is that the start of the `let` declarations - the variable names - line up.